# Have vimwiki set filetype only within wikihome

Tags: vim

I've started to use [Vimwiki](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2226) to create a personal wiki. I'm a big fan of the plugin, but unfortunately it hijacks all my Markdown files and sets their `filetype` to `vimwiki`.

This is happening with `.md` and `.markdown` files.

How can I tell vimwiki to only change the `filetype` if the file is in the wiki directory I have set?

Here are the vimwiki-related lines from my .vimrc

```
let s:vimwiki = {}
let s:vimwiki.path = '~/Dropbox/vimwiki'
let s:vimwiki.ext = '.wiki'
let s:vimwiki.syntax = 'default'
let s:vimwiki.diary_rel_path = 'journal/'
let s:vimwiki.diary_index = 'index'
let s:vimwiki.diary_header = 'Journal'
let s:vimwiki.diary_sort = 'asc'
let s:vimwiki.ext2syntax = {'.wiki': 'default'}
let g:vimwiki_list = [s:vimwiki]
```

I have also tried varying values for ext2syntax, including none at all and `{'.md': 'markdown'}`, which I believe is the default, but I have had no luck at all with anything changing. Any `.md` file is set as `ft=vimwiki`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished by replacing the global vimwiki_ext2syntax variable. Place the following in your `.vimrc`

```
let g:vimwiki_ext2syntax = {}
```

Comment: Now you can mark your own answer as correct.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue, but Ryan's answer didn't fix it. [This issue](https://code.google.com/p/vimwiki/issues/detail?id=146) on the old Google Code page suggests placing this fix in your `.vimrc`:

```
let g:vimwiki_global_ext = 0
```

Now files outside the wiki with the wiki page extension will not have `filetype=vimwiki`. This allows me to use Markdown (`.md`) with vimwiki and have the benefits of the vimwiki plugin while not overriding normal Markdown files outside of the wiki.